# How to create Calender control in jsp page using Struts 1.3

Tags: jsp, calendar, struts, struts-1

I am creating a web application using Struts 1.3 Framework. Can any one guide me how to create calender control using Struts 1.3 in JSP.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/datetimepicker.html

Answer (score 0):

Very easy is use [JQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). You may use it as an `input` tag or `html:text`, you should provide the `id` attribute to bind to UI widget.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using the [Jquery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Easy to integrate and looks nice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: "<%=request.getContextPath() + "/images/Calendar.png"%>",
  buttonText : "Calendario"
});
$(function() {
    $("#fechaIni").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true
    });
});
</script>

<input id="fechaIni" value="<%= fechaInicial %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html:text  property="toDate" styleClass="form-control" styleId="toDate" />
                        
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#toDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
</script>
```